# Google geocode API can't find address returned by the place API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places-api, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I can't get google's geocode api to recognize the address:

The Squaire 12
Am Flughafen
60549 Frankfurt am Main
Germany

The Squaire is a building at the airport in Frankfurt. It doesn't appear to have a normal street address, but a number of businesses in The Squaire have addresses like "The Squaire NUMBER". For example:

- ALEX: [The Squaire 17, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany](https://www.google.com/maps/place/ALEX+Frankfurt+The+Squaire/@50.0526911,8.5683829,78m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x3cc441ae39321b67!8m2!3d50.052795!4d8.568673)
- Bilfinger Facility Services GmbH: [THE SQUAIRE 13, Am Flughafen, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Bilfinger+Facility+Services+GmbH/@50.0532033,8.5709144,84m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xe263ab1350db84a2!8m2!3d50.0531461!4d8.57108)

But no matter what I do, I can't get addresses like that recognized by the google geocode api at:

- [The Squaire 12, Am Flughafen, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=The%20Squaire%2012,%20Am%20Flughafen,%2060549%20Frankfurt%20am%20Main,%20Germany)
- [The Squaire 12, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=The%20Squaire%2012,%2060549%20Frankfurt%20am%20Main,%20Germany)
- And lots of other variations

The maddening thing is that the places API finds the place I'm looking for when I search for "squaire" near the airport:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=XYZ&location=50.0509194,8.5684084&radius=1000&keyword=squaire

The matching result has: `place_id: ChIJY9ZMLL4KvUcRxZhQ3e-7ask`. When I query the details endpoint:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=XYZ&placeid=ChIJY9ZMLL4KvUcRxZhQ3e-7ask

I get `formatted_address: "THE Squaire 12, Am Flughafen, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany"`, but that's exactly the address that won't work in the geocode api.

And when I use the reverse geocode api with the place_id:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=XYZ&place_id=ChIJY9ZMLL4KvUcRxZhQ3e-7ask

I get `formatted_address: "plug and work Frankfurt, THE SQUAIRE Conference Center, THE Squaire 12, Am Flughafen, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany"`. Which still doesn't work in the forward geocode api:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=plug%20and%20work%20Frankfurt,%20THE%20SQUAIRE%20Conference%20Center,%20THE%20Squaire%2012,%20Am%20Flughafen,%2060549%20Frankfurt%20am%20Main,%20Germany

Comment: Why is this at -1? Could the down voter comment so I can make the question better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google GeoCoding API - returns ZERO\_RESULTS but the location shows on Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500751/google-geocoding-api-returns-zero-results-but-the-location-shows-on-google-map)

Comment: @miguev This question was open first

Comment: Yes, indeed, but the other question has the currently-correct answer. The answer here was correct previously, but is no longer so, because of the way Issue 10585 was fixed. Developers looking at this question would benefit greatly from looking at the other one. If there is a better way to encourage that "forwarding", I don't know of it, please show us.

Comment: @miguev The only reason the other question has the currently-correct answer is because you answered it there. If you put the same answer here, I'll mark it correct here (if not, I can self-answer). And for anyone else coming to this question, the right issue is [11031](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11031).

Comment: Fine by me, I didn't think that would be such a good idea, having two contradictory answers in the same question. Let's give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue in the Geocoding API: [Issue 11031](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11031).

It has been fixed in late January, so that Geocoding API will always return the same result/s as Google Maps:

- [The Squaire 12, Am Flughafen, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=The%20Squaire%2012,%20Am%20Flughafen,%2060549%20Frankfurt%20am%20Main,%20Germany) ==> `"formatted_address" : "Am Flughafen, The Squaire 12, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany"`
- [The Squaire 12, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=The%20Squaire%2012,%2060549%20Frankfurt%20am%20Main,%20Germany) ==> `"formatted_address" : "The Squaire, 60549 Frankfurt am Main, Germany"`

This is actually a side effect of how [Issue 11031](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11031) was fixed, and is a departure from the original behavior of the Geocoding API. xomena's answer was valid at the time he answered, the official recommendation from the Google Maps API documentation was indeed to use Places API Text Search. This is on longer the case, as you'll notice if you re-read the [New Forward Geocoder FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq).

Comment: I should also add that I was able to get the highway off-ramp that leads to "The Squaire" building changed in google mapmaker to be labeled as "The Squaire" (as @xomena suggested) so even before the referenced issue was addressed, this specific address became resolvable via the geocoding API.

Answer (score 1):

Google Geocoding API service doesn't work with business listings. You should use [Places API search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) service instead of Geocoding API to search businesses.

You can combine Places API autocomplete with Geocoding API as suggested in the best practices article. In this case you can get place ID from autocomplete and use it in Geocoding API.

Please take a look at the Geocoding best practices:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices

Hope it helps!

Comment: The documentation says, "Unambiguous queries such as complete postal address strings (for example, “48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont, NSW, Australia”) are best handled by the Geocoding API web service." I believe I have an unambiguous postal address string. It doesn't seem like it should be an issue if the address is for a business or now.

Comment: If the address string can be found only in business listings, Geocoding API forward geocoding filters it out. If you need this address in Geocoding API you should add it via [Map Maker](https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker) setting 'Address' category during the address creation. In your example place ID ChIJY9ZMLL4KvUcRxZhQ3e-7ask has types "establishment","point_of_interest", there is no "street_address" type. That's why it's not searchable with forward geocoding.

Comment: Ah. Okay, through the map maker interface I found the listing, I went to edit it's address and saw that it indeed was missing the street and number. But I could only select a pre-existing street for the name, and none of the suggestions were right. I tried to add the name "The Squaire" to an existing unnamed ramp leading to the building, but that edit was denied. At least I understand why it's not available via the geocode api now and it's just a political issue getting the change made.